# Let $f(x) = x^4 + 2x^2 - 6$ and let E be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: galois-theory, minimal-polynomials, splitting-field

Let $f(x) = x^4 + 2x^2 - 6$ and let E be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
(a) Find roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of $f(x)$ such that $E = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$. What are the other roots of $f(x)$ ?
(b) Compute $[\mathbb{Q}((\alpha + \beta)^2) : \mathbb{Q}]$.
(c) Compute $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha + \beta) : \mathbb{Q}]$.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$
(a) Notice that $f(x) = x^4 + 2x^2 - 6 = (x-\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{7}})(x+\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{7}})(x-\sqrt{-1-\sqrt{7}})(x+\sqrt{-1-\sqrt{7}})$.
Then, Case 1: $\alpha = \sqrt{-1+\sqrt{7}}$ and $\beta = \sqrt{-1-\sqrt{7}}$;
or Case 2: $\alpha = -\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{7}}$ and $\beta = -\sqrt{-1-\sqrt{7}}$.
Which in both of the cases $\alpha$ cannot be represent in terms of $\beta$ and $\beta$ cannot be represent in terms of $\alpha$.
So, $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{7}}, \sqrt{-1-\sqrt{7}}) = \mathbb{Q}(-\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{7}}, -\sqrt{-1-\sqrt{7}})$. $\textbf{But how do I prove this is true ?}$

(b) for case 1: if $\alpha = \sqrt{-1+\sqrt{7}}$ and $\beta = \sqrt{-1-\sqrt{7}}$
Then, $(\alpha + \beta)^2 = (\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{7}} + \sqrt{-1-\sqrt{7}})^2 = -2 + 2i\sqrt{6}$.
Notice that $-2$ and $2$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$. So, $\mathbb{Q}((\alpha + \beta)^2) = \mathbb{Q}(-2 + 2i\sqrt{6}) = \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{6})$.
Let $c = i\sqrt{6} \implies c^2 = -6 \implies c^2 + 6 = 0$.
Also, by Eisenstein’s criterion we know that $x^2 + 6$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. And $x^2 + 6$ is monic polynomial.
So, the minimal polynomial of $c$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $m_{c, \mathbb{Q}}(x) = x^2 + 6$.
Hence, $[\mathbb{Q}((\alpha + \beta)^2) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{6}) : \mathbb{Q}] = $ degree of $m_{c, \mathbb{Q}}(x)$ which is equal to $2$.

(c) Since, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha + \beta) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$. $\textbf{But how do I prove this is true ?}$
Then, $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha + \beta) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta) : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] \times [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}]$
$= [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta) : \mathbb{Q}(\beta)] \times [\mathbb{Q}(\beta) : \mathbb{Q}] = 4 \times 4 = 8$.
By Tower Law.

$\textbf{Are these correct ?}$
$\textbf{Also, how do I prove that}$ $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{7}}, \sqrt{-1-\sqrt{7}}) = \mathbb{Q}(-\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{7}}, -\sqrt{-1-\sqrt{7}})$
$\textbf{and}$ $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha + \beta) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$ $\textbf{are true ?}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me abbreviate your four roots to $r,s,t,u$. Note $s=-r$ and $u=-t$, so any field containing $r$ automatically contains $s$, and any field containing $t$ automatically contains $u$. So, extending the rationals by $r$ and $t$ gives you all four of the roots and hence gives you the splitting field $E$.

Now, let $x=r+t$. You have shown $x^2=-2+2i\sqrt6$. So, $(x^2+2)^2=-24$, so $x^4+4x^2+28=0$. If you can show that this polynomial is irreducible over the rationals, then you have proved that $x$ has degree four over the rationals, which answers (c).

Comment: I still did not get the second part, isn't that proving that $x^4 + 4x^2 + 28 = 0$ only proves that $[\mathbb{Q}((\alpha + \beta)^2) : \mathbb{Q}] = 4$. But why it proves that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha + \beta) : \mathbb{Q}] = 8$ as well ?

Comment: $(r+t)^2$ has degree two, not four, over the rationals, and $r+t$ has degree four, not eight, over the rationals.

Comment: okay, I think I got it, I made a mistake in the comment since I already find that $[\mathbb{Q}((\alpha+\beta)^2) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2$ in part (b)

Comment: If my answer settles your question, you have the option of "accepting" it by clicking in the check mark next to it. If your question is not settled, what remains to be discussed?

Comment: sorry, I forget to click it